# How to determine the authorization in Joomla

Tags: joomla, authorization, joomla2.5

After login i use need to set up redirect to custom page. How to catch this authorization in `onAfterRoute` event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to this path:

```
JOOMLAROOT/components/com_user/controller.php
```

in function register_save(), find this code:

```
if ( $useractivation == 1 ) {
            $message  =  JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE_ACTIVATE' );
        } else {
            $message = JText::_( 'REG_COMPLETE' );
        }
```

after line put this code:

```
$this->setRedirect('/Your Custom Page Address', $message);
```

Comment: as i said - i use `onAfterRoute` event in the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built in redirect in either the Joomla user login menu item or the standard Joomla login module. Both offer the option to redirect a user after a successful login. In the case of the module, you would need to create a menu item pointing to the custom page, but that's easy enough to do.

Is there something you need to do other than just a simple redirect? If not, then just use the system as it is designed.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small plugin that handles the redirect after login.
After a user has been logged in, the event onUserLogin is triggered, and you could simply do a redirect when the event is called.

Avoid any core hacks, since you'll allways end up having a hazzle during updates.

The code for a plugin like this could look like this:

```
class plgAuthenticationMyredirect extends JPlugin{

   function  onUserLogin ($user, $options){
      $link = 'index.php?option=.....';
      $msg = 'Message to show after login';
      $app = JFactory::getApplication();
      $app->redirect($link, $msg); 
   }
}
```